# Are Chef Automate and Chef Delivery the same?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm evaluating a continuous delivery solution in Chef. I got two concepts: Chef Automate and Chef Delivery. Looks like they all can do continuous delivery. Are they the same products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef Delivery is no longer offered as a standalone product. It was subsumed into Chef Automate as "Workflow." Automate is actually a suite of three products: Workflow, Visibility, and Compliance.

https://www.chef.io/automate/